# Calculating $\int x^4/(x^2+1)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I'm having trouble with the indefinite integral

$$\int \frac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

I suspect it should be easy, but I don't see it.

Any suggestion or hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably mean to put $dx$ in there. Without it, the integral is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: decompose the fraction into a sum of rational fractions. Start with

$${x^4\over (x^2+1)^2}=1-{2x^2+1\over (x^2+1)^2}=1-{2\over x^2+1}+{1\over (x^2+1)^2}$$

Next step is

$${1\over (x^2+1)^2}={1\over 1+x^2}-{x^2\over (1+x^2)^2}$$

The result is

$$\int {x^4\over (x^2+1)^2} dx={x\over 2(x^2+1)}+x-{3\over 2}\tan^{-1}{x}+cte$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Since $x^4=x^4-1+1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)+1$ we have
$$\frac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)+1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}=1-\frac{2}{x^2+1}+\frac1{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also integrate by parts

$$\int\frac{x^4}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int x^3.\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}x^3.(-\frac{1}{x^2+1})-\frac{3}{2}\int x^2.(-\frac{1}{x^2+1})dx=-\frac{x^3}{2(x^2+1)}+\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{x^2+1-1}{x^2+1}dx=-\frac{x^3}{2(x^2+1)}+\frac{3}{2}(x-\arctan(x))=\frac{2x^3+3x}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{3}{2}\arctan(x)=x+\frac{x}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{3}{2}\arctan(x)+cst.$$